# How to find the UUID of serial port Bluetooth device?

Tags: android, bluetooth, uuid

I want to receive data from the serial port bluetooth device to android phone. But i don't know the UUID of that device how to find the UUID of that device?

Answer (score 26):

Extending what pwc said about the UUID being 0x1101, this is the 16 bit version of the UUID as far as I can tell. I could not work out how to instantiate an UUID with a 16 bit UUID. But as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164138/simple-bluetooth-data-receiver-android) says you can do it by:

`private static final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb");`

This worked for me to connect to a serial bluetooth module I bought from Deal Extreme

Comment: So what does all the rest of the UUID mean?  I know 1101 means serial port protocol.

Comment: @JPM The rest of that UUID comes from the [base UUID](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/assigned-numbers/service-discovery).

Answer (score 7):

If the device is using serial port profile, then yes, it is simply:

```
0x1101
```

For other pre-defined options, see the list of pre-defined UUIDs as listed in `javax.bluetooth`:

[UUID](http://www.avetana-gmbh.de/avetana-gmbh/produkte/doc/javax/bluetooth/UUID.html).

Answer (score 6):

The UUID for the SPP Serial Port service is defined by the Bluetooth SIG to be 0x1101.

Answer (score 0):

In the Android Bluetooth API documentation: 


[Create RFCOMM Socket to Service Record - UUID](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord%28java.util.UUID%29).

Answer (score 0):

Just open your device  in adb shell type sdptool and browse you got your device UUID

Answer (score 0):

From API level 15, you can query the supported features (UUIDs) of the remote device, use the method on the BluetoothDevice object obtained in the search:

```
public ParcelUuid[] getUuids ()
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get Device UID by simple Calling

```
perticulerDevice.getUuids()[0].toString()
```

Comment: How does one do this pre-15?